# Here is my code, I am follwing a tutorial on making a weather app but I am getting errors while syncing with gradle

Tags: android, error-handling, build.gradle, retrofit2, dependency-resolver

Here are the dependencies I used:

```
dependencies {
    implementation ("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation ("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation ("androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0")
    testImplementation ("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation ("com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.1.0")
    implementation ("com.square.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.square.retrofit2: retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")`
}
```

It is showing the following errors:

```
Failed to resolve: com.square.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0
Failed to resolve: com.square.retrofit2: retrofit:2.9.0
```

Using different versions (instead of 2.9.0) also showed the same error. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct dependencies are:

```
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
```

You can verify them here:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/converter-gson/2.9.0
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.9.0